# How do I invoke methods/access properties of an OCX control via Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ocx

I am writing the scripted GUI tests for a system which I do not have access to its source code; and I want to invoke the methods and access the properties of an OCX control (specifically the MSFlexGrid control) as I could not find any other way of finding out the number of rows and columns, as well as the data values in each cell, in the MSFlexGrid control used.

I've tried the Win32API, Win32OLE, and FFI libraries, but I still couldn't gain access to the OCX control for scripting. I may be missing something, and I don't know what.

Comment: can't use those 'cos I'm testing fat client apps. Have also tried using AutoItX, but to no avail.

Comment: why no avail for ole and autoit?

Comment: MSFlexGrid is not an OLE Automation object like MSExcel, so I cannot use win32ole.
Other than my attempts in accessing the properties I want using AutoIt, posts in AutoIt forum also confirm that AutoIt cannot access the properties and methods MSFlexGrid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but maybe try going through iron ruby to use the .net interop?

Comment: To use the .net interop, I would need to use .net attributes. Does IronRuby support attributes? Google does not turn up any information on this.